# Make a child element take a third of the parent container (Parent is styled using grid-layout)

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'd want one child element to be 1/3 the size of its parent container and the other 2/3. The parent container is in a main container that uses grid-layout. 
The parent container in question spans 2 columns of the main container it is contained in.

I've tried using margin, but it doesn't work: when I switch from a small screen to a large screen it moves to leave a gap.

```
<div class="main-container" style="display:grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr"> 1
    <div></div>
    <div class="parent-container" style="grid-column:span 2">
        <div class="child-1"></div>
        <div class="child-2"></div>

    </div>
</div>
```

css code I've tried:

```
.child-1{
     margin-left:-20%;
 }
```

Child-1 must be 1/3 of parent-container and child-2 2/3 of parent-container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the nested grid container. The dotted borders signify the width that the child elements take from the parent container. The solid borders are for the main container's child elements. Rest is explained in comments.

```css
.main-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr; /* 1/4th for Extra, 2/4th for Parent, 1/4th for Extra */
  grid-auto-flow: column; /* Normal flow is row */
}

.parent-container {
  display: grid; /* Nested Grid */
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr; /* 1/3rd for Child 1, 2/3rd for Child 2 of parent container*/
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}


/* Extra styling for snippet, you just need the above logic */

.main-container {
  font-size: 1.15em;
  font-family: Sans-Serif;
}

.parent-container {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.parent-container>div {
  background: #6660CE;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px dotted black;
}

.main-container>div {
  background: #6660CE;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="extra">Extra</div>
  <div class="parent-container">
    <div class="child-1">Child 1 </div>
    <div class="child-2">Child 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="extra">Extra</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect answer. I just found grid-column-start could work as well.

Answer (score 1):

Simply give the parent element two columns with `grid-template-columns`, where the second column is twice the size of the first column (i.e. `1fr` and `2fr`).

This can be seen in the following:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
}

.child-1 {
  background: red;
}

.child-2 {
  background: blue;
}

.child {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child child-1"></div>
  <div class="child child-2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I have the main-container set to 1fr 2fr 1fr because this is used to style the header. (logo, search, user-icon). Below the header, I need the sidebar (1/3 of main-container) and parent-container(2/3 of main-container columns)

Comment: So just set `grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr` on the outer container and `grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr` on the inner container :)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.child:nth-child(1) {
  grid-area: 1 / 1;
  background-color: #9341aa;
}

.child:nth-child(2) {
  grid-area: 2 / 1 / span 1 / span 2;
  background-color: #ab41aa;
}

.child:nth-child(3) {
  grid-area: 3 / 1 / span 1 / span 3;
  background-color: #cab332;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `calc`, something like this should do the trick:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="main-container">
    <div></div>
    <div class="parent-container">
        <div class="child-1"></div>
        <div class="child-2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.parent-container{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.parent-container .child-1,
.parent-container .child-2{
    width: calc(100% / 3);
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}
```